# iOS Handle IAP download fail on SKDownloadStateFailed state

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Our app provides in app purchases to apple hosted extra content which the user downloads, but some users are reporting problems with the download.

It seems to fail halfway through, alert the user and resets all buttons etc to allow the user to buy again (for free as they have already purchased). If the user then tries to re buy or restore purchases in the app it still fails. The following code is what handles a failed state.

```
-(void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads{
for (SKDownload *download in downloads){
    switch (download.downloadState){
        case SKDownloadStateActive:{
            //code removed for post
            break;
        }  
        case SKDownloadStateCancelled:{ break; }
        case SKDownloadStateFailed:
        {
            //log the error
            NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", download.transaction.error.localizedDescription);

            //let the user know
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ download failed, please try again later", download.contentIdentifier] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

            //post notification - caught in view controller for updating buy buttons etc
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperDownloadFailedNotification object:download userInfo:nil];

            // This should delete the download assets from the Cache folder.
            NSError* error = nil;
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:download.contentURL error:&error];
            if(error){
                //
            }

            //finish the transaction
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:download.transaction];

            break;
        }

        case SKDownloadStateFinished:{
            //code removed for post
            break;
        }

        case SKDownloadStatePaused:{
            break;
        }

        case SKDownloadStateWaiting:{
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked around stack overflow and elsewhere and what little examples I can find on in app purchases all do the same as above. Any help or info would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem and just found a possible resolution in Apple's FAQ on IAP:
Q: How do I resolve the "You've already purchased this In-App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded." error message?
A: You are getting the "You've already purchased this In-App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded." error message because you did not call SKPaymentQueue 's finishTransaction:method in your application. Calling finishTransaction: allows you to remove a transaction from the payment queue.

I think I will ask my IAP engine to check whether there is any IAP is being processed when app exits(my problem occurs when user stopped the app while downloading), if yes, calls finishTransaction:.

Hope it helps.